# Is mysql.connector reporting incorrect paramstyle? [mysql-connector-python 8.0.29]

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python, pep249

Using mysql-connector-python 8.0.29 `mysql.connector.paramstyle` reports 'pyformat'.

Assuming I've correctly understood the docs here https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle the following ought to be a valid SQL insert when passed to `execute()` - given the table exists, which it does - and is invoked with the arguments `['Python', 10]`:

```
INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%(c1)s, %(c2)s)
```

However, when this is executed, the following error is returned:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

This strongly implies that the format `%(<name>)s` isn't being interpreted as a value placeholder.

However, if I change the insert to the below and invoke as before the insert succeeds.

```
INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

According to the docs however `%s` is paramstyle 'format' not 'pyformat'.

So is `mysql.connector.paramstyle` misreporting the supported style?  If not, what am I missing?

Background: I'm porting an in-house SQL library from Java to Python.  As it's a library it should be neutral to the RDBMS vendor and therefore needs to generate appropriate updates and queries for all the formats PEP 249 allows, based on the reported `paramstyle`.

```
# paramstyle.py
import mysql.connector
conf = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 3306,
    'database': 'test'
}
c = mysql.connector.connect(**conf)
with c.cursor() as csr:
    csr.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lang')
    csr.execute('CREATE TABLE lang(name VARCHAR(50), score INTEGER)')
    csr.execute('INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%(c1)s, %(c2)s)',
        ['Python', 10])
    #csr.execute('INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%s, %s)',)
    #    ['Python', 10])
c.commit()
c.close()


$ python3 paramstyle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paramstyle.py", line 13, in <module>
    csr.execute('INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%(c1)s, %(c2)s)',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 559, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Aside: Why does PEP 249 allow these five different approaches to argument placeholders?  Surely one would have been sufficient?  Doesn't this complicate client code that needs to be connector independent?

Comment: I suspect the answer to the aside is historic. Before PEP249, there were already a bunch of drivers that worked differently. Rather than force them all to change to a single format, the different styles were accomodated.

Comment: Doesn't `$(name)s` require that the parameters be a dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar Ah, interesting.  That seems to imply the `(name)` part is required for 'pyformat' when providing a dict, but should left out when providing a sequence (tuple, list).  Doesn't that also imply 'named' can *only* be used with a dict?  And, conversely 'qmark' and 'numeric' can *only* be used with a sequence?  And therefore, to implement a neutral library you need to not only use the right placeholder but also provide the args in either a sequence or a dict, as required by the paramstyle supported by the implementation in question?

Comment: `pyformat` means that it allows the extended format `%(name)s` for named parameters in addition to the printf-style `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyformat` doesn't mean you have to use `%(name)s` style of parameters. It means that these are allowed for named parameters, *in addition to* printf-style `%s` for ordered parameters.

But to use these, you have to put the parameters in a dictionary to associate the names. So it should be:

```
    csr.execute('INSERT INTO lang(name, score) VALUES (%(name)s, %(score)s)',
        {'name': 'Python', 'score': 10])
```